# How reliable is Android's relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm new to Android, and i'm working on a project of my own for a while.
I'm extremely cautious about causing problems with different handsets.

The layout I am trying to make it very complex. I spent a lot of time trying to work out how I will do it with lots of nested weighted linearlayouts or tablelayouts.

Then I came across relativelayout. I made a xml file, dropped some buttons on as placeholders and in eclipse it looked great. I thought to myself, nah, that'll never work. Put it on two phones, it's exactly how I wanted it ( of course not with buttons though ).

I was shocked that it worked so well, but want to know how likely I am to come across issues on other devices?

I am using dip for my elements, am I right in thinking no matter how many dip I use to fill the page ( for example, if I have a combined height of 1,000 dip ), that it will just scale that to fit on the phones display? Or is there a particular amount of dip I should be aiming for?

I've looked at examples online, and tried making this myself, I need some words from someone who has done this and knows from experience if it's reliable/not, this is something hard to find online anywhere.

Thanks,

Comment: Your question's title says how reliable is linearlayout but then the question seems to ask about relativelayout, not sure what you are looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` are "reliable". Most normal apps use either or both. They are widely used and do what they are meant to do. That said, they're not magic. You should go through either or preferably both of the  [training](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) or [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on supporting multiple screens. It will give you a better understanding of (among other things) supported screen densities, supported screen sizes and what dp/dip really means.

For example, about your 1000dp question, the [multiple screens doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) says the following:

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

meaning that there are a huge number of screens that do not fit 1000dp height (most in fact).